# How can i run multiple queries in dataflow template?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, dataflowtask

I am performing Mysql to bigquery data migration using jdbc to bigquery template in dataflow.

But while performing "select * from teable1" command on mysql, i also want to insert the selected data to another table in same database for some reason.

How can i perform both select and insert queries in dataflow template? I got error when used semicolon between two queries.

Comment: Did you try with an `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Yes. i got "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" error.  I think we cant use select and insert together for union all

Comment: The issue should be in your query. The JDBC IO connector simply execute the query, simple or complex, and get the result

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The Jdbc to Bigquery template will write all data you read to the table specified under "Bigquery output table" (`<my-project>:<my-dataset>.<my-table>`), so there is no need to write the insert statement.

(The parameter is "outputTable" for gcloud/REST)

Comment: @Dhairyaa The Jdbc "to Bigquery" template is not for your use-case. The mysql query is only used to extract the data. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch?hl=en_US#java-database-connectivity-jdbc-to-bigquery

Comment: Actually, I want to perform incremental load. So for keeping track of migrated data , I am saving there primary key in different table. That is why I want to perform insert in source database

Answer (score 0):

As @PeterKim mentioned the [JDBC to BigQuery termplate](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#java-database-connectivity-jdbc-to-bigquery) could be not the best approach for your use case.

You could try to use that template as reference and modify it to write into MySQL, in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48371180/10409068) you will find an implementation about how to make an insert into MYSQL database.

After modifying the [pipeline source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/JdbcToBigQuery.java) you can create a [custom template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates).